# how to desearlize the xml to List<Object>

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to desearlize xml string to list

**This is my actual xml string**

```
<root>
  <student>
    <Header>
      <userid>1</userid>
      <name>user1</name>
      <createddate>2017-05-03T00:00:00</createddate>
    </Header>
  </student>
  <student>
    <Header>
      <userid>2</userid>
      <name>user2</name>
      <createddate>2016-05-03T00:00:00</createddate>
    </Header>
  </student>
  <student>
    <Header>
      <userid>3</userid>
      <name>user2</name>
      <createddate>2015-05-03T00:00:00</createddate>
    </Header>
  </student>      
</root>
```

Object has been created against the xml

```
public class UserHeader
{
    #region Properties
    [XmlElement("userid")]
    public int user_id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string displayName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("createddate")]
    public DateTime created_date { get; set; }


    #endregion
}
public class Student
{
    public UserHeader Header { get; set; }
}


[XmlRoot("Root"), XmlType("Root")]
public class User
{
    [XmlElement("eConnect")]
    public List<UserHeader> userList { get; set; }


    private static User ListUsers()
    {
        User list = new User();
        XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User));
        string ct = "XML String attached the sample";
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(ct))
        {
            list = (User)mySerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        return list;

    }

}
```

When trying to read the data from xml string, was getting  below error saying that

```
<root xmlns=''> was not expected
```

Suggest us how can i get the list of user information from the xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[XmlRoot("Root"), XmlType("Root")]
```

and

```
<root>
  <student>
    <Header>
      ...
```

XML is case-sensitive. `root` is not the same as `Root`.

Comment: That's a separate question. You already have a `List`, look for the student in the `List`

Comment: i can do the filter stuffs from the object level... what my question is.. during the serialization level it is possible ?